# Make a list of attribute from a list of objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, genetic-algorithm

i'm trying to make a genetic algorithm, and to collect the values of fitness function i made a class pair so i can sort with a lambda function. The class is simple, just this:

```
class Par(object):
def __init__(self,cromosoma,valoracion):
    self.cromosoma=cromosoma
    self.valoracion=valoracion

def __str__(self):
    return ("Cromosoma: {0}\nTiene valoracion: {1}".format(self.cromosoma,self.valoracion))

def __repr__(self):
    return ("Cromosoma: {0}\nTiene valoracion: {1}".format(self.cromosoma,self.valoracion))
```

So after i sorted the list of chromosomes with this:

```
poblacionOrdenada=sorted(evaluacion, key=lambda par: par.valoracion, reverse=False)
```

I want to select the 50% best but the function i want to recibe just chromosomes not the pair object. So how can i get a list of just chromosomes without a for? maybe with another lambda function?

i don't want to use a for because i have to select several time in different functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Produce a list of just the `cromosoma` attributes with a list comprehension:

```
[par.cromosoma for par in poblacionOrdenada]
```

Once you have that list you can use it for various different function calls.

Comment: Of course...what a stupid question! i was trying more difficult stuff.
Remember to try easiers first! TY

Answer (score 0):

To select the chromosomes of the first 50% of the strains from the sorted list:

```
answer = [strain.cromosoma for strain in poblacionOrdenada[:len(poblacionOrdenada)/2]]
```

EDIT: (Since I lack domain knowledge)

Switch `[:len(poblacionOrdenada)/2]` with `[len(poblacionOrdenada)/2:]` if the best 50% strains are in the end of the list.